# Product of neighbourhoods

Tags: real-analysis

If I define product of two sets $A, B$ such as:
$$A*B=\{a*b: a\in A , b\in B\}$$
And then take two neighbourhoods $U_a$ and $U_b$ of points $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, ($\delta > 0$)
$$(a-\delta,a+\delta)\subset U_a$$
$$(b-\delta,b+\delta)\subset U_b$$

**Question:** What is then their product?

This is perhaps somewhat elementary, but I am slightly confused about the matter and wouldn't want to jump on false conclusions.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is equivalent to ask, what is the product (defined by you) of two open intervals $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$. Let me provide you some examples, and let us assume that all numbers are positive. Let $x\in (a,b)$ be any point, then $\{x\}*(c,d) = (cx,dx)$. Due to the fact that everything is positive, and that the multiplication is a continuous functions  we obtain $(a,b)*(c,d) = (ac,bd)$.

I guess, you can figure out the general case simply.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to figure out the general case now.

Comment: @DahnJahn There are $9$ cases, $3$ for each interval: 1) $a>0$ $b>0$ 2) $a<0$ $b<0$ and 3) $a<0$ but $b>0$, the same cases for $(c,d)$. I described the case $1,1$. For $2,1$ you have $(a,b)*(c,d) = (ad,bc)$

Comment: The more "interesting" cases are of course when when $0$ is in at least one of the intervals.

Comment: To clarify: For the case $1,3$ it'd be $(bc,bd)$? If that is so, then I suppose I see the logic behind it. Still, I find it slightly baffling; followup question: if I know $a<x<b$, $c<y<d$, $a<0$ and $b,c,d>0$, how do I arrive at $ad<xy<bd$?

Comment: Also, in my neighbourhood question, I have to look at these possibilities for $(a,b)$: $(+,+),(+,-),(-,-),(+,0),(-,0),(0,0)$? (Ignoring symmetric problems such as $(-,+)$) Thanks.

Comment: @DahnJahn You shall understand how each of these cases reduces to the ones I described.

Comment: Yes, I think I do, thanks. Is there a simple way of answering the inequalities question, or should I perhaps post it as a separate question?

Comment: I shall accept this answer, as it, together with the comments, led me to understanding of the problem. That being said, the "fuzzy numbers" answer is absolutely lovely.

Answer (score 1):

With the following setup you are on the safe side:

Introduce "fuzzy numbers" by means of
 $$(a,\epsilon)\ :=\ [a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon]\qquad(a\in{\mathbb R}, \ \epsilon\geq0)\ .$$ 
Defining sum and product of such numbers by
$$\eqalign{(a,\epsilon)\oplus(b,\delta)&:=(a+b,\ \epsilon+\delta)\ ,\cr 
(a,\epsilon)\odot(b,\delta)&:=(a\cdot b,\ |a|\delta +|b|\epsilon+\epsilon\delta)\ \cr} $$
you are guaranteed
$$(a,\epsilon)+(b,\delta)\ \subset\ (a,\epsilon)\oplus(b,\delta)$$
and
$$(a,\epsilon)\cdot(b,\delta)\ \subset\ (a,\epsilon)\odot(b,\delta)$$

Comment: I love this approach! Thanks.